# Initialize StateProvider in Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I just want initialize provider only one time with widget param. For some reason I can't use .family. I'm not sure if this is the right way. Can you check this? Thank you.

```dart
StateProvider<String> valueStateProvider;

class Widget extends HookWidget {
  final String value;

  Widget({@required this.value}) {
    valueStateProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => this.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the right way to do this. There is special provider type for this situation. [ScopedProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/ScopedProvider-class.html).

```dart
final scopedProvider = ScopedProvider<String>((_) => throw UnimplementedError());

class Widget extends HookWidget {
  Widget({@required this.value});
  final String value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ProviderScope(
      overrides: [scopedProvider.overrideWithValue(this.value)],
      child: AnotherWidget()
     );
  }
}
```

So you can use scopedProvider in AnotherWidget. Yay!